# Word 2010 vba to APPEND table to Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, append

I have a Word 2010 vba script which is meant to take the contents of a table and append it to an Excel 2010 file. I have the code almost complete but am struggling to get the insertion point moved to the next empty row in excel.

The idea is that the 2nd and 3rd etc time the macro is run the data is appended into the Excel file underneath the last lot of data.  I'm struggling to reference the last excel row used from Word to make that the insertion point.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub ExportBookmarksToExcel()
    Dim myTable As Table
    Dim RowsCount As Integer
    Dim ColumnsCount As Integer
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oExcel1 As Object
    Set oExcel1 = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\richard\Desktop\DummyFolder\GettingFieldsFromWordToExcelDemo\Exported.xlsm")

    For Each myTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        Dim WS As Object
        Set WS = oExcel1.ActiveSheet

        RowsCount = myTable.Rows.Count
        ColumnsCount = myTable.Columns.Count

        MsgBox oExcel1.CurrentWorkbook.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        For i = 3 To RowsCount
            For j = 1 To ColumnsCount
                WS.Cells(i, j) = myTable.Cell(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
    Next myTable

    oExcel1.Close (True) 'Closes the workbook by saving changes.
    Set oExcel1 = Nothing
    Set oExcel = Nothing
    ActiveDocument.Repaginate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are three issues is in:

```
oExcel1.CurrentWorkbook.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

1) Excel Model Object has no `CurrentWorkbook` property for `Application` object

2) there is no `ActiveSheet`

since Word is your *client* application and Excel is the `server` one, you don't have such things as `ActiveWorkbook` or `ActiveSheet` qualifications implicitly assumed should your excel range references lack a `workbook` and/or `worksheet` qualifications

this means that `Rows.Count` means nothing in your context

3) xlUp is an Excel enumeration name

since you're using *late* binding you don't have any Excel Application *enumerations* (like `XlDirection`) available, so you have to use their *real* names value (like -4162 for `xlUp`)

that said you code can be rewritten as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportBookmarksToExcel()
    Dim myTable As Table
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oExcelWb As Object
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oExcelWb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\richard\Desktop\DummyFolder\GettingFieldsFromWordToExcelDemo\Exported.xlsm")

    With oExcelWb.ActiveSheet '<-- reference open workbook active sheet
        For Each myTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(-4162).Offset(1, 0).Row '<-- get current column A last non empty cell row
            For i = 3 To myTable.Rows.count
                For j = 1 To myTable.Columns.count
                    .Cells(lastRow + i - 3, j) = myTable.Cell(i, j)
                Next j
            Next i
        Next myTable
    End With

    oExcelWb.Close True 'Closes the workbook by saving changes.
    Set oExcelWb = Nothing
    oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing
    ActiveDocument.Repaginate
End Sub
```